# Gnuplot matching tics

Tags: gnuplot, multiple-axes

I'm trying to plot data with two different x-axes with the following code:

```
reset
# Settings
set grid
set x2tics
set xtics nomirror

plot './data/N.dat' u ($1*c1)/f_offset:($2*c2) w lp ls 1,\
 '' u ($1*c1)/f_offset:($3*c2) w lp ls 2,\
 '' u ($1*c1):($2*c2) w p ps 0 notitle axis x2y1
```

where c1,c2 and f_offset are constants. The last line is there only to get the second set of ticks. This works fine but the ticks on x and x2 axes are not aligned. It is a minor thing but it does look weird with the grid, which is aligned to the first axis. Is there a simple solution I'm missing or do I have to set the values manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is a simple solution, although there might be something similar as an option I'm not aware of. Simply setting the ticks manually works in this case:

```
set x2tics 0.9*f_offset,0.005*f_offset,0.935*f_offset
set xtics nomirror 0.9,0.005,0.935
```

I don't know why I didn't try that earlier.